# Can you mount more than one ADLS2 instance in Databricks?

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-lake, delta-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

What is the best practice to set up a DEV/TEST/PROD environment for the data lakehouse / delta lake architecture? Do you have a separate ADLS2 instance for DEV/TEST/PROD each, or do you host all three in one ADLS2 instance? Can you even mount more than one ADLS2 instances in Datbricks?

Comment: 3 separate instances will be better and you can mount multiple ADLS2 instances in databricks.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have separate storage accounts for each environment. There are multiple reasons for that:

- It's simpler to control access to the data - usually in prod environment only service accounts have access to the data, but dev & test environments have other requirements.
- You're avoiding influence of dev/test on the prod & vice versa. Each [storage account has limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account) on the number of API calls and bandwidth. This is especially helpful when you're trying to do load testing that may affect all environments if you have shared storage account.

You can mount as many storage accounts as you want, but you need to understand that everyone in workspace will have access to the data in that mount, and it will depends on the permission of the service principal or shared signature used for mount.  More secure way would be to use credentials scoped to the specific cluster(s).